# How to make two overlapping time series sequential without losing the seasonality of each time series when there is an overlap?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I have weekly price data along with Date column for an item where for each year there are two variants of the same item.
Item A(variant 1) starts from Jan to June while Item B(variant 2) starts from April to October.
I am currently creating a hedging strategy which will be used to procure the item.
I was thinking of vertically stacking Item A and Item B so that i can have a sequentially clubbed data from Jan to October.
There is an overlapping period from April to June.
I want to create the sequential time series so that for the overlap period both Item A's and Item B's prices are considered(in such a way so that the seasonality is conserved) and none ignored.
Final goal is to have a vertically stacked dataframe based on Both Item A's and B's actual prices in it.